# Which option will auto increase/decrease the height of table in a div

Tags: html, css, button, html-table

Please help me! Menu of my site resembles with menu from this [website](http://ccplusplus.site50.net/).

In this menu:

```
width: 30%;
margin-left: -25%;
height: 98%;
background:#ffab23;
position: fixed;
top: 1%;
bottom: 1%;
z-index: 1;
border-radius:15px;
```

is included a table with a column and many rows, in each row is a button.

How to make the table to increase / decrease automatically as the menu.

Part of menu:

```
<div id="menu" align="left" style="direction:rtl; overflow:auto;">
<div style="direction:ltr;">
<table height="100" width="80%" align="left">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <a href="#introducere" class="myButton">1. INTRODUCERE</a>
    </td>
    </tr>...
```

The button:

```
.myButton {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 3px 3px #caefab;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 3px 3px #caefab;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 3px 3px #caefab;
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #77d42a), color-stop(1, #5cb811) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #77d42a 5%, #5cb811 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#77d42a', endColorstr='#5cb811');
background-color:#77d42a;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
border:1px solid #268a16;
display:inline-block;
color:#306108;
font-family:calibri;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:2% 24px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #aade7c;
width:79%;}


.myButton:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #5cb811), color-stop(1, #77d42a) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #5cb811 5%, #77d42a 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5cb811', endColorstr='#77d42a');
background-color:#5cb811;}


.myButton:active { position:relative; top:1px; }
```

Comment: set its height as `auto`..

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `height:auto` if you want to automatically increase/decrease the height, and if you want the same for width then use `width:auto`.

See the button [with text INTRODUCERE](http://jsfiddle.net/GYnMR/1/) and when you enter a lengthy text then it will [auto increase](http://jsfiddle.net/GYnMR/).

Comment: I set this: style="direction:rtl; overflow:auto;">
<div style="direction:ltr;"> - for scroll bar in left side of menu and this stop that I wanted. If I will remove this selection, all is good. Sory for my english...

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. What exactly do you want? Can you show some example in jsfiddle or something?